# Verify that the periodic Sturm- Liouville system has a symmetric operator

Tags: sturm-liouville

Verify that the periodic Sturm- Liouville system has a symmetric operator

The ones that I know is that the Sturm-Liouville periodic  system is:

$L[y]=\lambda r(x)y=0$

$x_{1}< x< x_{2}$

$y(x_{1})=y(x_{2})$

${y}'(x_{1})={y}'(x_{2})$

where $L=D[p(x)D]+q(x)$ and where

$p(x_{1})=p(x_{2})$

As I show that an Sturm- Liouville equation of the form:

${y}''+\lambda y=0$

be the periodic Sturm- Liouville system.I've to confess that I'm a bit lost, can anyone give me a hint ?

Comment: Maybe you should consider to respond to your various old questions before posting again and again new ones without reacting to answers.

Comment: I don't think you mean this, do you?: $L[y]=\lambda r(x)y=0$.